# What is the root cause of ppa, source list errors because I keep getting them?

Tags: ppa, repository

I'd like to know the cause of ppa, source list, gpd errors when running :

```
sudo apt update
```

What is happening is that my Ubuntu will be working completely fine and error free when running the update command.
I usually only use Ubuntu repos,  PPA's from list at [Ubuntu Updates](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppas) , except if I need a specific package and then will use some other PPA's and remove after the install.

I almost never compile source, install from source. 
I do use tarball files from time to time if that is the only way software is available for install. I usually use command line for installs: sudo apt install, wget, curl. I'll use software center on occasion. I just started using synaptic a bit more. I've used aptitude as well.

I do not usually install games, or install from low reputation looking sites.

I'm just sure what is causing issue? Do I need to mainly use only one method of installing? Cmd line, Aptitude, Synaptic, etc... Is using multiple package managers the issue, sketchy ppa's?

EG: Just the other day I tried installing Nginx and got a key error, but went to Nginx site and they had posted a fix.
I often get some line like:
W: cannot read or write to preferences... dot a directory 20 , or something similar to that.

I have gotten key errors, source list, preferences type errors.
I've found fixes online (but not really root cause)and remove the errors but it has become really frustrating so now I am trying to dig more into " Root Cause Issue" and eliminate getting the errors in the future.

Comment: post the error messages lol . Also I am not sure there is any such thing as an "official standard ppa" , as far as I know, only the ubuntu repos are official and standard, not ppa.

Comment: Now your post is tl;dr and you did not post any error messages.

Comment: Bodhi, I apologize, but I am not currently getting errors. I am just trying to find out what is possibly causing these errors and learn so I can stop possibly doing something that may be causing issue.

Comment: The problem why we can't answer your question like this is that the package system is quite complex and there are many different error types you can get, all caused by something different. Trying to write an answer would result in a huge list of things that could possibly go wrong and how to avoid those, and it would still likely be incomplete. General advice is to always only install from the official repos. If that is not possible, try to find a trustworthy PPA and use that. Avoid installing downloaded .deb files, binaries or compiling from sources, always prefer the package manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, *it it ain't broke, you cannot fix it...*

That said, sometimes there are issues with the way that packages add their sources to the apt source list. Opera has a bug where it is added with the `https//` rather than `https://` and apart from inspecting the entries when you notice them added, there is no way but the error to know that something went wrong. It is not your doing so much, but it IS up to you to fix it if you do not want to get the error (do not wait for someone else to fix or you might be waiting a while).

Now, if you have a specific error message which is troubling you, then you can post the output and someone can help with that. Otherwise, as Byte Commander said, we would be shooting in the dark to give you a list of all possible things which *could* go wrong.